# Is it possible to have Maven profiles with multiple ids or re-use a profile using different names?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

For one of our projects we have a complex multi-module setup with an entire tree of pom-files. For one of the plugins we use it would be very convenient if a profile could have multiple id's. This would spare me to have to repeat the same configuration for several profiles (we have about 7 profiles, but - at least for that plugin - three different configurations would do.

So, to spare me from having to repeat each config several times (and then keep those copies in sync) it would be very handy to simply allow multiple ids for each profile.

I know that this is not possible directly as sketched in the below example (Maven would yell at me if I feed it such a file with a profile that has multiple ids) but is there some trick or workaround to achieve that effect? I.e. factor out the config part and re-use it in multiple profiles? Or "map" those 7 "global" profiles (i.e. profiles also used in other pom's) to 3 "local" ones and define configs for only those 3?

Hope I could make myself clear...

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile_1</id>
          **<id>profile_2</id>**
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <... complex config here...>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Comment: If you have seven profiles, you have likely constructed something overly complex.

Comment: That may well be but - as usual - it is "historically grown".

Comment: What do these profiles do?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot give a profile multiple IDs.

What you can do is activate multiple profiles through the same property.

```xml
<profile>
  <id>profile-1</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>profile.both</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>profile-2</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>profile.both</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
</profile>
```

Then run `mvn -Dprofile.both`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, it's kind of the opposite of what I was asking for, namely using a single id or property to trigger multiple profiles. I would want to trigger different sets of profiles using a single id or property. Or can one specify multiple properties for a profile?

Comment: To clarify, I told you that what you want is not possible, but provided you with an similar alternative. To answer your question in your comment, no, you cannot specify multiple activation properties. See https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd.